# How can I get the UpdateSourceTrigger settings from code for a DataGridColumn binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, code-behind

I have a DataGrid control that has a TextColumn

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dvm.Data}"
              Name="GrdName"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Margin="5"
              SelectionMode="Single">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1"
                                Binding="{Binding Path=Col1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                                Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have a custom control that requires me to test what the UpdateSourceTrigger setting is, but I am having trouble accessing that from code.  I would like to do something like this:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(GrdName.Columns[0], DataGridTextColumn.BindingProperty);
```

But, BindingProperty is not actually a dependency property, so I can't do that.  Does anyone know how I would go about getting the binding expression for the Binding property for that column so I can get the UpdateSourceTrigger setting?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Binding` property is not a `DependancyProperty` so you will have to access using normal public properties.
So you will have to do a bit of casting as the `Binding` property in `DataGridTextColumn` is type `BindingBase` you will have to cast as `Binding` to access `UpdateSourceTrigger`.
And since `DataGridTextColumn` is derived from `DataGridBoundColumn` you can cast from that to make it a bit more generic

Something like this should work:

```
   var columnUpdateSourceTrigger = ((GrdName.Columns[0] as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding).UpdateSourceTrigger;
```